# php implode not working with sql oracle

Tags: php, oracle, implode

Trying to put all results from oracle table into php variable using implode with this code but is not working. 
What is wrong in here?

```
$sql = oci_parse($ora_con, "SELECT * FROM TABLE");
oci_execute($sql);

while (($row = oci_fetch_row($sql)) != false) { 
    echo $result = implode(',',(array)$row[0]);  
}
```

And the result is: resul1result2result3result4

Instead of: result1, result2, result3

Comment: Casting $row[0] to an array will give you an array with a single element

Comment: join is alias on implode, nothing special there. but how he is doing is wrong. First you populate array, and at the end you call implode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're fetching a row at a time, then imploding a single-item, which ends up with no comma (as there's only one). You output that, then loop to the next result - which puts it in the output.

Instead, perhaps try the following, which constructs an array of the results, and then echos the imploded results:

```
$results = [];
while (($row = oci_fetch_row($sql)) != false) {
    $results[] = $row[0];
}
echo implode(',', $results);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [choult's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35749579/3775731) is to fetch all rows in the resultset directly using [`oci_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php):

```
$sql = oci_parse($ora_con, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE');
oci_execute($sql);
oci_fetch_all($sql, $result, 0, -1, OCI_NUM);

echo implode(',', $result[0]);
```